# Изменение типа данных у элементов со свойством contentEditable со строки на число

Tags: javascript

Необходимо задать тип вводимых данных - число, но не срабатывает. Как исправить?

```js
let pallets = document.getElementsByClassName('pallets');
for (let i = 0; i < pallets.length; i++) {
  pallets[i].contentEditable = true;
  if (pallets[i].innerHTML.length === 0) {
    pallets[i].innerHTML = ' ';
  } else {
    pallets[i].innerHTML = parseInt(pallets[i].innerHTML)
  }
  console.log(typeof pallets[i].innerHTML)
}
```

```css
.pallets {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pallets"></div>
<div class="pallets">4</div>
<div class="pallets">5</div>
```

Comment: В `innerHTML` может содержаться только строка.

Comment: Если нужно работать со значением `parseInt(pallets[i].innerHTML)`, то присвойте его переменной. Не понятно зачем вы так делаете `pallets[i].innerHTML = parseInt(pallets[i].innerHTML)`

Comment: Мне нужно вручную заполнять большое количество ячеек, с которыми будут затем произведены математические операции. Думал попробовать сделать без инпута. Присвоить значение parseInt(pallets[i].innerHTML) переменной, не получится, т.к. числовых данных много и они меняются.

Answer (score 2):

У вас работает, но не совсем корректно и код надо запускать каждый раз после изменения полей. А вообще задача не такая простая как кажется на первый взгляд, например, кроме клавиатурного ввода необходимо учесть события вставки. Ниже код который позволяет ввести с клавиатуры только цифры.

```js
$(".pallets").on("input", function(e) {
  let val = $(this).html();
  if (val.match(/\D/)) {
    let pos = getPos(this);
    $(this).html(val.replace(/\D/g, ""));
    setPos(this, pos - 1);
  }
});

function getPos(elem) {
  elem.focus();
  let _range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  let range = _range.cloneRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(elem);
  range.setEnd(_range.endContainer, _range.endOffset);
  return range.toString().length;
}

function setPos(elem, pos) {
  elem.focus();
  if (document.selection) {
    let sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.moveStart('character', pos);
    sel.select();
  } else {
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(elem.firstChild, pos);
  }
}
```

```css
.pallets {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pallets" contentEditable></div>
<div class="pallets" contentEditable>4</div>
<div class="pallets" contentEditable>5</div>
```